# Check if public object property is set with variable as pointer

Tags: php, object

Ola!

So I got a $_POST looking like:

```
Array
(
    [name] => FooBar
    [sobject] => tbl_character
    [id] => 102
)
```

And a "SmartObject" like:

```
SmartObject Object
(
    [_settings] => Array
        (
            [table] => tbl_character
            [ignores] => Array
                (
                    [0] => leaderid
                    [1] => typeid
                    [2] => senderid
                    [3] => recieverid
                    [4] => imageid
                    [5] => fileid
                    [6] => professionid
                    [7] => id
                )

            [prefix] => tbl_
        )

    [id] => 102
    [worldid] => 
    [accountid] => 110
    [zoneid] => 
    [raceid] => 1
    [imageid] => 
    [name] => asd

    ... blabla more data
)
```

What I want to do is to loop through the $_POST and check if the keys match any public set property on my SmartObject like so:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if(isset($object->{$key})) {
    $object->{$key} = $value;
   }
}
```

When a value exists (ex. for id) the isset triggers and returns true, but when a value doesn't the isset wont return true.

`empty()` checks if a value is set.

`isset()` should check if the "variable" or "property" is there, not necessarily set to anything, right?

I believe this code worked fine for me a year ago, but now the if-statement wont trigger on name. Am I doing something wrong? Has the fundamentals of php changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about (if you are using PHP >= 5.1):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (property_exists($object, $key)) {
        $object->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Here's the documentation:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

From the official documentation:

> Note: As opposed with isset(), property_exists() returns TRUE even if
>   the property has the value NULL.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Though I got to ask, I do use php 5.4, but did the isset()-usage on object properties work prior to 5.1? In that case I must've used 5.1 or lower last time I coded on the project.